# Using grep to capture os name

Tags: grep, sh

In using grep I can do:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release|grep "NAME="
NAME="Ubuntu"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

Is there a way to get the capturing group of the name? For example, something like:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release|grep -P '^NAME="(.+)"$'
NAME="Ubuntu" # <-- how to just get 'Ubuntu' ?
```

I suppose one option would be this? But this seems a bit overkill:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release|grep -P '(?<=^NAME=")[^"]+'
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/os-release` is designed to be sourced.  Just use:

```
. /etc/os-release; echo "$NAME"
```

The dot in `. /etc/os-release` tells the shell to *source* the file.  That means that the commands in the file will be run as if they were in the current shell.

In `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh` and some others, we can use `source /etc/os-release` in place of `. /etc/os-release`.  The `source` keyword, however, is not part of the POSIX standard and is, therefore, not portable.  In particular, `source` is not supported by `dash` and `dash` is the default `/bin/sh` on many distributions.

#### Sourcing vs executing

We could also execute the file:

```
sh /etc/os-release; echo "$NAME"
```

However, this means that the commands in `/etc/os-release` are executed in a child process and, when the child exits, all the environment changes are immediately lost.  This means that, in our process, there will be no change to the variable `NAME`.  That is why, in this case, we use sourcing rather than executing.

Comment: oh perfect, thanks! One question: what does the `.` before the path do? Does `.` do the same as `$ source` ?

Comment: `.` is the command to _source_ a file.  I just updated the answer to include that.

Comment: got it thanks. Is `.` an alias for `source` when it's not part of a path or something?

Comment: @David542 The `.` command (meaning 'source') is part of the POSIX standard and therefore should be portable between POSIX shells, such as bash, dash, etc.  The `source` command in bash does the same thing but is not portable.